# sed command not working on AWS template

Tags: amazon-web-services, sed, command

I have a sed command I want to run on a file. The command adds a couple of lines in front of a string.

This is the sed command I want to run:

```
sed -i  "/<\/VirtualHost>/i\  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/cert/aws.cer \nSSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/cert/aws.key" ssl.conf
```

The JSON entry in the cloud-formation template User Date is:

```
"sed -i  '/<\\/VirtualHost>/i \\  \nSSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/cert/aws.cer \nSSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/cert/aws.key' /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf \n",
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unknown command: `S'
```

Can someone please help me fix the JSON expression?

Comment: The spaces after the literal backslash before the newline don't seem right; why are they there and does it help if you remove them?  `'/<\\/VirtualHost>/i \\    \n`...

Comment: Thanks Tripleee it worked.

Comment: Please add an Answer to close-off this Question (even if you answer your own question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spaces after the literal backslash before the newline don't seem right; why are they there and does it help if you remove them? '/<\/VirtualHost>/i \ \n... – tripleee Oct 1 at 3:45

Thanks tripleee for your answer